# Is there any literature on "re-normalisation" of denormalised data?

Tags: normalization, denormalization

I'm involved in a project, the core of which might be generously described as "re-normalisation" of denormalised data. (To be fair, the initial implementation took only the first 90% of the time budget. But, as you might expect, the myriad edge cases are taking the second 90%...)

Being mindful of this site's admonition to ask answerable questions rather than start discussions: is there any literature on this issue? Intuitively, it seems like an idea fraught with danger, and in this instance it's certainly turning out to be a quagmire. But is it, say, *provably* impossible to get right in some general way?

Comment: Why (in general terms) are you doing this transformation?

Comment: There were two databases A and B. Client chose to represent their data in A, which involved denormalising some of it: A was of a very specific morphology for a particular purpose, but allowed additional data outside its core schema by way of arbitrary attribute-value pairs. Client then had to represent the same data in database B, which, unlike A, was specifically tailored to representing the data model precisely. For "business reasons", it was decided that B would be populated (and updated) by "re-normalising" the parts of the data that had been flattened into those attribute-value pairs.